# VB 2010 Express - Review Order Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

My current project is to write a program that basically is a cash register for a pizza company.

The user enters the pizza, along with toppings, drinks, and sides.

I want to add a "Review Order Form" for when the user decides to check out. The form will pop up and inform the user of everything he/she has ordered. From there the user makes changes to the order as necessary then confirms and checks out.

I was wondering if anybody could give me any clues on how to display all of the items the user has ordered. I do have lists of all the items selected by the user. I am just unsure on how to display all of the items to the screen cleanly in a separate form.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. I hope you're open to some suggestions. First, take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You'll see that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Since we're not having a discussion, you can leave off things like "hi", "thanks", and "Johnny". Also, note how I changed your tags. What you used originally were not tags. Please click the "Tags" button near the top of the page to see what sorts of things are meant to be used as tags.

Comment: What kind of app is it?  Windows Forms?  Web app?  This will affect the answers you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you will want to store each item the user orders into a collection. Then when you want to review, you just iterate through the collection and output each item in the collection.